# Is it possible to combine tfpdf with fpdi?

Tags: encoding, fpdf, utf, iso-8859-1, fpdi

At this time, i fill an ISO-8859-1 pdf with fpdf and fpdi.
I want to transform the pdf in UTF-8. Is it possible to use tfpdf with fpdi in order to deal with UTF-8 pdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently only the outdated version 1 of FPDI is compatible with tFPDF. A simple demo is available on [this](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/legacy-v1/) page. Create this class:

```
class FPDF extends tFPDF {}
```

And load FPDI afterwards so it will extend this class.

An update for FPDI 2 will follow.

Comment: Is it possible to use FPDI 2 with tFPDF now?

Comment: You may check [this](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/issues/27#issuecomment-394741480) out.

Comment: It works with FPDI 2 for me.